# Unable to check/uncheck multiple checkboxes selectManyMenu by using single selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: checkbox

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox  label="#{lbl['lbl.pm.sr.all.states']}"
 value="#{suppliersReviewBackingBean.managedBean.allStates}">
 <p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true"
listener="#{suppliersReviewBackingBean.selectAllStates}"
update="stateListId" process="@this" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>          
<p:selectManyMenu label="#{lbl['lbl.pm.sr.state']}"
id="stateListId"
value="#{suppliersReviewBackingBean.managedBean.suppliersReviewSearchBean.dropDownStatesIdList}"
style="width: 252px;margin-bottom: 5px;height:113px"
showCheckbox="true"
disabled="#{suppliersReviewBackingBean.managedBean.disabled}">
<f:selectItems var="finState" styleClass="ui-state-disabled"
value="#{suppliersReviewBackingBean.managedBean.suppliersReviewSearchBean.statesList}"
itemValue="#{finState.stateId}" itemLabel="#{finState.stateName}">
</f:selectItems>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

This is the UI screen without selection:

[image]

This is the UI screen after selection (I need exactly solution like this):

[image]

I want to check/uncheck multiple checkboxes of `p:selectManyMenu` checkboxes  by based on single checkbox selection of `P:selectBooleanCheckbox`. I have tried many ways I didn't get exact solution.

Comment: plz, update the question, don't try to add it as a comment

Comment: thanks.... i will add accordingly

Comment: I don't want like this behaviour 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyMenu.xhtml

Comment: Please provide me solution if anyone knows......as soon as possible

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: HI Arcresu ,could you please  make it my post is globally ,i didn't get any response from any one